# Static kube config for EKS

Tags: authentication, kubernetes

I'm trying to generate static kube config for EKS that doesn't rely on AWS IAM (by configuring service account, role, etc). I'm a bit confused on how to do this. Would anyone mind to help me with this?

I tried to use this script. But it looks like I'm missing something.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gravitational/teleport/v14.0.1/examples/k8s-auth/get-kubeconfig.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem was found. It was due to insufficient role permissions.
I added **list** to the pods section.

```
- verbs:
      - get
      - list
    apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - pods
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).